# Generate random numbers for member of struct

Tags: c, random, struct

I would like to have the user define the number of random numbers they would like to be stored in a member of my struct.
Here is what I have so far.

```
struct BigInt {
int A;
int rdm;
};
struct BigInt A[300];
struct BigInt rdm[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

printf("Number");
int len;
scanf("%i",&len);

srand(time(NULL));
int i=0;

while (i!=len){
int r=rand()%10;
A[i]=rdm[r];

printf("\nr:%i\n",r);
printf("A[i]:%i",A[i]);
i++;
}
```

But I am getting strange values and it's not working as I expect it to be. I have no idea why, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. **Mind those warnings**, even treat them as errors. Edit: the compiler *may* complain for the mismatch between `"%i"` and `A[i]` in the `printf()` call.

Comment: `struct BigInt` has two members.

Comment: You're using `A` and `rdm` both as member names and as array names. The indicates that you haven't yet grasped what a structure is, and how it works.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler even compiles this code. You need a better understanding of structs.

Comment: Note that `struct BigInt rdm[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` initializes the first 5 elements of the 10 element array `rdm`.  That's because each `BigInt` has two members, so the `0` initializes `rdm[0].A` and the `1` initializes `rdm[0].rdm` and the `2` initializes `rdm[1].A`, etc .  It could also be written: `struct BigInt rdm[10]={ { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9 }, };` and would get the same effect.  You could also use: `struct BigInt rdm[10]={ { 0 }, { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 }, { 6 }, { 7 }, { 8 }, { 9 } };` which would set the `.A` members, leaving `.rdm` zeroed.  Etc.

Comment: [mcve] will really help you. Besides what comments you've already got, you didn't say what you expect the output to be, and what inputs you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet of code solves your problem basing on your comment below. You haven't completely understood how to use structure perhaps. Note that to use member of a structure you must use the . symbol

```
struct BigInt {
    int *A;
};

struct BigInt bigIntVar = {
    NULL
};

printf("Number");
int len;
scanf("%i", &len);

bigIntVar.A = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));

srand(time(NULL));
int i = 0;

while (i != len) {
    int r = rand() % 10;
    bigIntVar.A[i] = r + 1;

    printf("\nr:%i\n", r);
    printf("A[i]:%d", bigIntVar.A[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I'm tolerably certain that the revised structure definition is not appropriate.  I could be wrong, of course — it isn't clear from the question what is wanted, or why the disparity in the sizes of the arrays, or … well, quite a lot about the question isn't clear.

Comment: I agree with you that the question isn't completely clear. Should I remove the answer?
I think that the user want up to 300 random number amongst the number in the rdm array, that in this case has 10 values.

Comment: `{}` is an invalid C initializer (though gcc without `-pedantic` accepts it). You may want to replace with `{0}`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to... well practically everything here. The goal was to have a member A of type BigInt be an array of any size of random numbers from 1 to 10. Since I asked the question I got a better hold on struts but am still a bit confused as to how I achieve what I'm going for. [This](https://repl.it/JdgI/15) is my revised code as of this second, but I'm still having a problems.